# How I can change configuration of toolbar in catalog?

Tags: magento2, toolbar

I have a **catalog_category_view.xml** and I try to change the toolbar.

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
    <action method="setDefaultListPerPage">
        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
    </action>
    <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
    </action>
    <action method="addPagerLimit">
        <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

But it does not work.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor::addPagerLimit
```

By default, Magento has:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
    <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
               name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
        <!--
            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage">
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit">
            <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit">
            <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit">
            <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">6</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit">
            <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">8</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label">
            <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">all</argument>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">All</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit">
            <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit">
            <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">6</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit">
            <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">9</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label">
            <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">all</argument>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">All</argument>
        </action>
        -->
    </block>
    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
    </action>
</block>
```

How I can change configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Now I found solution for change numbers from admin panel.

Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Storefront.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-product-listings-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is likely because you're calling the action on the wrong block type.

In the example that they give you, they're calling the action methods on the block:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
```

Try changing your referenceBlock name from `category.products.list` to `product_list_toolbar`.

Comment: Yes, I know about it. Same result: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar::addPagerLimit

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1404 here you find solution

Comment: What is a toolbar, Can anyone explain

Comment: @Sri The toolbar in this instance refers to the block on the product list page that has the "Sort By" dropdown.